# 'str' object is not callable for os.path.sep()

Tags: python, string, callable

```
import os

def ls_component(path):
    ls = os.path.sep(path)
    print(ls)
    return ls

ls_component('D:\SDP\speaker-identification-master\data\eval')
```

This is the code I'm trying to implement but Im getting the error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hp\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 14, in <module>
    ls_component('D:\SDP\speaker-identification-master\data\eval')

  File "C:\Users\hp\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 10, in ls_component
    ls = os.path.sep(path)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Help help me

Comment: What are you intentions of using `os.path.split` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.path.sep` is a string constant not a function. It returns the path separator (eg. `\`) used by the underlying OS. So doing `os.path.sep()` is like doing `"\"()` which is why you get the error that `str` is not callable

If you want to split the path into its components use `os.path.split()`